# Is there any way to return an entire namespace via the translate function in i18next？

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

in my case，i need get the entire namespace as an object，is there any can do this？
i have try this code，but just return undefined。

```
 // the bookingPage is a namespace
t('bookingPage',{ returnObjects: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the `t` function, `t` function returns a string.

You can get an access to the entire `i18n` object which has methods for this.

```js
// your-component.jsx

const YourComp = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  console.log(i18n.store.getResourceBundle('en', 'bookingPage')); //<-- will return the entire namespace
  return <div>Bla</div>;
};
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as such :]

Answer (score 0):

```
// your-component.jsx

const YourComp = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  console.log(i18n.getResourceBundle('en', 'bookingPage')); //<-- will return the entire namespace
  return <div>Bla</div>;
};
```

Worked for me!